# rollback hibernate reactive transaction

Tags: transactions, micronaut-data, hibernate-reactive, micronaut-test

Is it possible to rollback the hibernate reactive transaction when using micronaut data hibernate reactive? Let's say we are writing a test to create a user in the db. We would like to rollback that transaction after the test completes.

Annotating the test class with javax transactional annotation does not seem to help.

How would one go about rolling back the transaction in hibernate reactive?

Comment: Do you want the roll back to happen after every test or after all the test have completed?

Comment: @ShingJo after every test

Comment: Wouldn't this be a Micronaut configuration rather than a Hibernate configuration?